# FAQ Slightly Confusing?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, faq-for-site

The second bullet under "What it's not about" states:

> what language/engine/SDK you should learn next, including which technology is better, which technology to use, or what technology some particular game used

The word "including" is what really throws me off. If I'm skimming I may look at this and say "Ok. No what should I learn type questions! Got it!" and skip the rest because the including implies types of "What Should I learn" type of questions when I really don't think "Which technology is better, which technology to use, or what technology some particular game used" really fit into.

I know I'm being a little picky here but I think either separating them out into separate bullets, or removing the "including" would make this much more clear which with the number of closed topics we get may actually justify this. If people don't agree that's fine. It's just an observation I made.

Thoughts?

Comment: I agree. I propose it be changed to something along the lines of "technology selection, including what language/engine/SDK you should use or learn next, which is better, or which was used for some particular game"

Answer (score 2):

I based it off bullet point #3 from the programmers faq https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq but I guess it got unwieldy. I just made them all separate points.